# Mysql ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR on findOne with loopback

Tags: mysql, angularjs, npm, webpack, loopbackjs

I am currently building a webapp using AngularJS, Loopback and MySQL. It worked fined for a while and recently most of the request I made to loopback from my front-end started to fail with an internal server error.

```
Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'scopes' in 'field list'
```

I am using the Loopback Angular SDK to make my request in my frontend. I don't really understand why it is searching for a column scopes since i call it to search for a user when I have its id.

```
    $scope.user = !$scope.isLoggedIn ? {} : Appuser.findOne({
    filter: {
      where: { id: Appuser.getCurrentId() }
    }
  }).$promise.then(function(res){
    $scope.user = res;
  });
```

I recently started to use webpack on this app and also recently reinstalled all of my node modules and I don't know if it may have had an impact but I suspect so because when I'm reverting to commits at a time it all worked fined the problem still happen. However since I'm using npm and a package.json for my modules I don't understand what could have gone wrong.

Comment: Here is a related [github issue](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/3395).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it do below (I'm using mysql connector)

```
ALTER TABLE AccessToken ADD COLUMN `scopes` TEXT NULL;
```

I found new field at `./node_modules/loopback/common/models/access-token.json`.

```
"scopes": {
    "type": ["string"],
    "description": "Array of scopes granted to this access token."
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After some more research, I found an answer. It was a problem with npm that installed the wrong version of loopback because I did not fix my dependencies versions number and had `"loopback": "^3.0.0"` when I needed `"loopback": "3.0.0",`.
The `^` mean that npm may take a more recent minor version which in my case happened and totally broke my connection with my database.

If it ever happens with anyone else don't forget to delete and reinstall your node modules afterward.